# Method of undetermined coefficients for complex binomial series?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to show that when $|z|<1, \alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, then $$(1+z)^{\alpha}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty {\binom{\alpha}{n}}z^n$$ where $${\alpha\choose n}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}$$
using method of undetermined coefficients.

I think I can use Taylor expansion to solve it but I don't see how method of undetermined coefficients is even relevant. Tips would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility could be (but perhaps not the one you are supposed to use):

You know from $g(z)=(1+z)^α$ that $(1+z)g'(z)=αg(z)$. Now use a power series with undetermined coefficients for $g$ and use power series identification. This is permissible inside the radius of convergence since then the differentiation can be switched with the limit in the series summation.

Careful application of index shifts leads directly to a simple recursion for the binomial coefficients.